# Why does boost::is_same<int const&, boost::add_const<int &>::value equal false?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming

I'm working through ["C++ Template Metaprogramming" by Abrahams & Gurtovoy](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321227255)" 
This isn't actually in chapter two but is something I tried whilst working on the first exercise (2.10, 2.0) which is confusing me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

std::string display(bool b)
{
  return (b ? "true" : "false");
}

int main()
{
   using namespace std;

   cout << display(boost::is_same<int const&, boost::add_const<int &>::type >::value) << "\n";

     return 0;
}
```

The output is 'false'. 
However if I remove the references, i.e. 'int const' and 'int'. The output is 'true'.

Comment: BTW You can avoid your `display` function by setting `std::cout << std::boolalpha;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you tried the same thing with pointers, as in

```
boost::is_same<int const *, boost::add_const<int *>::type>::value
```

you'd discover that it is also false, since `boost::add_const<int *>::type` generates `int *const` type, which is obviously not the same as `int const *`.

Essentially the same thing happens with references, i.e. `boost::add_const<int &>::type` is an attempt to generate `int &const`. Formally, type `int &const` is illegal in C++ - cv-qualification cannot be applied to the reference itself. So, `boost::add_const` is designed to be a no-op in this case, meaning that `boost::add_const<int &>::type` generates `int &` again.

Comment: I get it now. I assumed add_const<int&> would give me int const& but it tries to add the const *the other side*, thanks

Answer (score 9):

You cannot add const to a reference, it would be `int& const` which isn't possible.

Just like with a typedef, adding qualifiers isn't a text replacement but something that works on the entire type.

Comment: The implication being (in case it wasn't clear) that `boost::add_const<int&>::type` is still just `int&`.

Comment: As illustrated in the examples of the official documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/add_const.html

Comment: And indeed `int & const` is illegal. If it were allowed, it would be superfluous because a reference is implicitly const already.