# Trying to use std::add_const to turn T& into const T&

Tags: c++

I have a T& which has a const and non-const version of a function. I want to call the const version of the function. I try using std::add_const to turn T& into const T& but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here is a simple example.

```
void f(int&)
{
    std::cout << "int&" << std::endl;
}

void f(const int&)
{
    std::cout << "const int&" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int& r = a;
    f(static_cast<std::add_const<decltype (r)>::type>(r));
}
```

Output: `int&`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6217453/951890

Answer (score 6):

Type traits are a very laborious way of approaching this.  Simply use template type deduction:

```
void f(int&)
{
    std::cout << "int&" << std::endl;
}

void f(const int&)
{
    std::cout << "const int&" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
const T& make_const(T& t) { return t; }

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int& r = a;
    f(make_const(r));
}
```

Comment: Nice. But add an overload if you want `make_const(1)` to work.

Comment: Instead of adding an overload, just add a `const`.

Comment: @aschep no make const needed in that case, just f (1)

Comment: it would increase usability by making it possible to write `&make_const(1)`. or with the naming I'd prefer, `&const_ref(1)`. e.g. for providing an argument to a C function.

Comment: @Alf: How many C APIs do you know of that have a parameter of type `const int*`?  And if it is `const void*`, then I would want to control the type, not have it implied by the literal.  For example, `&implicit_cast<const int&>(1)` looks good.

Answer (score 4):

References cannot be cv-qualified, so `std::add_const` applied to a reference type leaves it unchanged. In this particular case you should just do

```
f(static_cast<const int&>(r));
```

but in general you will have to transform the reference type `T` like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct add_const_to_reference {
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct add_const_to_reference<T&> {
    typedef const T& type;
};

template<typename T>
struct add_const_to_reference<T&&> {
    typedef const T&& type;
};
```

Comment: I think I'd prefer `const T&` to `const T&&`, as the later is entirely pointless

Answer (score 2):

`std::add_const` does nothing for a reference, since a reference can't be const qualified, only what it references can be.

In your case, a simple solution is to make a const version:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int& r = a;
    const int &const_r = r;
    f(const_r);
}
```

or if you don't want to specify an explicit type:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int& r = a;
    const auto &const_r = r;
    f(const_r);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to prevent treating an expression as mutable, you could use [`std::cref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int& r = a;
    f(std::cref(r));
}
```

Here `cref` returns a `std::reference_wrapper<const int>` struct, which implicitly converts back to `const int&`.

If you want to actually do something with the corresponding reference-to-const-something type, either create your own trait as @Brian suggested, or use `decltype` on your own wrapper function as @BenVoigt suggested, or you could do something like this if you really still want to take advantage of `cref`:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int& r = a;
    using ConstRefT = decltype(std::cref(r))::type &;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *general* answer to how to do manual overload resolution is to cast the function pointer, i.e. here `static_cast<(void(*)(const int&)>(f)(r)`. Uhm, I hope I got the parentheses right. In this specific case you can alternatively just cast the argument, `f( static_cast<const int&>( r ) )`, since `static_cast` can do any implicit conversion.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int& r = a;
    f(static_cast<int const&>(r));
}
```

---

If you want to generalize that by composing the standard library's type modifiers, then you can do it like this:

```
f(static_cast<std::remove_reference<decltype(r)>::type const&>(r));
```

Since that's pretty ugly I recommend just defining a general `const`-adder, or for an ad-hoc thing declaring a reference to `const` locally and use that as argument.

A general `const`-adder can go like this:

```
template< class Type >
auto const_ref( Type const& r ) -> Type const& { return r; }
```

Comment: And if the function wasn't overloaded, you just did a C-style cast between function pointer types.  Really bad idea.  (`boost::implicit_cast` or initialization to do that would be safe, though)

Comment: @BenVoigt: re "C-style cast", you can just use a `static_cast`. i updated the answer to show you. i didn't have much time when i wrote this, sory.

Answer (score -1):

`const_cast` is what you need.
See: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: This is an implicit conversion, no cast needed.