# C++: concise way to create const reference to modiable object

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I have a class foo with a method bar().
I want to be able to use bar() on the object, but also use bar() to create a (modified) copy of the object.
I declare the methods as:

```
void bar();
```

and

```
foo bar() const;
```

The second option works fine with a const foo object, but errors on a non const foo object:
Cannot convert void to foo.

Now I can overcome this by:

```
foo obj2 = ((const foo&)obj1).bar();
```

I am interested in a more concise cast, since the casting gets irritatingly verbose in (other) cases. A workaround has been to append the name of the const method with a c, as in:

```
foo barc() const.
```

I would hope for something like `(const)obj.bar()`, but obviously, that will not do.
Any ideas?

Edit:

I solved it by a simple macro.

`#define _const(o) ((const decltype(o))o)`

using it  as

```
_const(obj1).bar()
```

The underscore appears to be optional.

Another good/better approach through templates, see
[answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705213/trying-to-use-stdadd-const-to-turn-t-into-const-t)

Comment: Perhaps overloading is not the right solution here. You should consider simply renaming your methods to indicate the different purpose they fulfil. It's not clear to me what you are gaining by giving both `bar()` methods the same name.

Comment: There are `std::add_const` and friends, but this smells more like a design problem than anything else. You could also do `auto const &obj1c = obj1;` and then you can use `obj1c` for invoking `const` members.